# How do I not add an icon after a link with an image in it

Tags: css, css-selectors

We use css to add icons to links to files such as PDFs, Word, Images, etc. For example:

```
<a href="mypdf.pdf">Download PDF</a>

a[href$=".pdf"]::after {
    content: "\00a0\f1c1";
    display: inline;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

How do I tell CSS to not add an icon if the link is around an image?

```
<a href="mypdf.pdf"><img src="someimage.gif"></a>
```

I've tried numerous versions of the following with no luck.

```
a::after img {content: ""}
```

thanks,
Shauna

Comment: You can use 'not' attribute in css to avoid image tag and apply on others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Using Javascript, you could query the A tag selectors and then check their children[0] to see if the tagName is an IMG tag, if it is not... create an icon element and add the classList for your ICON then insert the icon element after the a tag element. Depending on how/what your icons are or what determines what icon will be placed behind your a tags, conditionals can be added to check what that logic may be and then add an ICON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css `a[href$=".pdf"]::after` is targeting extremely wide -- it is literally any `<a href="...pdf">` instances. It will add the icon independent of what child elements it contains.

You can add another, more specific, selector such as `a.noicon[href$=".pdf"]::after { display: none;}` to remove the icon from  `<a href="mypdf.pdf" class="noicon"><img></a>`. You cannot create a selector that targets a child's parent without using Javascript to target it.

It is much wiser to create 'additive' styles that are *as specific as you need* them such as `p a[href$=".pdf"]::after` to target all links within paragraphs or `.pileoflinks a[href$=".pdf"]::after` to target links within a very specific class.

Most ideally, create an instance where someone must make a conscience decision to add the icon: `a.download-pdf::after` and `<a href="[anylink]" class="download-pdf">`

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector will explain a more technical perspective.

Comment: Thanks, we have hundreds of links to PDFs and much fewer links to images, so I think we will go with adding a class to the link on images even though not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you could do the following:

The following code queries the a tag selectors within a parent element then two helper functions, one that inserts an element after another element, the icon after the iterated a tag value. The other that checks the file extension of a href string helper to identify if the target a tag has an image as its child.

We pass our selectors into a function that loops over the nodeList and checks each iteration for children elements to filter out IMG tags. NOTE: this conditional may need to be changed if you will have child elements directly within the `<a>` tag that are not `<img>` tags. Then we extrapolate the file extension from the ***href*** string using `el.href` and pass that into another helper function to get the extension. Create an `<i>` tag and then use a conditional to check the ***extension*** and add the proper ***icon*** to the ***iconClass***. Then use `icon.classList` to add the class *(glyphs or other icon types)* depending on what you are using.  Lastly we add the icon after the `a` tag element using the helper function `insertAfter(icon, tag)`, pass in the ***icon*** and the ***`value`***  of our `<a>` query => `tag`.

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('#container A')

const insertAfter = (el, referenceNode) => {
  // get parent node of referenceNode then insertBefore el.nextSibling
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
//Helper function from w3c to get extension of path
const getExtension = (path) => {
  let baseName = path.split(/[\\/]/).pop(), // extracts file name from full path
    // (supports separators `\\` and `/`)
    pos = baseName.lastIndexOf("."); // gets the last position of `.`
  if (baseName === "" || pos < 1) // if the file name is empty or ...
    return ""; // the dot not found (-1) or comes first (0)
  return baseName.slice(pos + 1); // extracts extension ignoring "."
}

// function to check element 
const checkImgFunction = (el) => {
  // check all elements in this case we are querying 
  // a tags within the parent element #container
  el.forEach(tag => {
    // condtional to check if the tag does not have children
    // assuming only a tags with textNodes are the targets
    // this conditional may need to change for your needs 
    // if your tag will have `children` that are not images
    // and you wish to include them in your truthy logic
    if (!tag.children[0]) {
      // get the extension type using the helper function getExtension()
      let ext = getExtension(tag.href),
      // create the <i> tag to hold our class glyphcons
      icon = document.createElement('I'),
      // instantiate a class variable that will hold the icon class
      iconClass;
      // conditional to check ext/s
      // one could have an array for this
      // my example is very basic using a if/else consitional
      // could also use switch statements here as well
      if (ext === 'txt') {
        iconClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip";
      } else if (ext === 'mp3') {
        iconClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-music";
      } else if (ext === 'pdf') {
        iconClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate";
      } else {
        iconClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-link";
      }
      // now we add the class/s to the icon element
      icon.classList = iconClass;
      // helper function to add the icon AFTER the a tag element...
      insertAfter(icon, tag);
    }
  })
}
// call the function
checkImgFunction(el)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="container">
  <a href="mypdf.pdf"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=Image.com"></a>
  <a href="mypdf.txt"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75/0B0B0B/FFFFFF/?text=Image.com"></a>
  <a href="mypdf.txt">Text link </a>
  <a href="mypdf.mp3">MP3 link </a>
  <a href="mypdf.pdf">PDF link </a>
  <a href="mypdf.pdf"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75/00FF00/FFFFFF/?text=Image.com"></a>
  <a href="mypdf.pdf"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Image.com"></a>
  <a href="mypdf.pdf">PDF link </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. I'm actually trying to get away from a JavaScript solution, but I appreciate your thoughtful and well documented solution.